# Does fiber bundles admits good properties of covering spaces?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, complex-geometry, fibre-bundles, covering-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be non compact complex manifolds and $f:X\to Y$ be a holomorphic fiber bundle with fibers $F$ such that $f^*:\pi_1(X)\to\pi_1(Y)$ is injective and let for any $f_1,f_2\in F$ there exists a biholomorphic map $\psi:F\to F$ such that $\psi(f_1)=f_2$ and $\psi\in Deck(X/Y)$. My question is $\pi_1(X)$ a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(Y)$? If not can we put some extra conditions(apart from finite fibers) such that $\pi_1(X)$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(Y)$?

Any comments or suggestions on how to think about this question is highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Just having finite fibers with an abstract biholomorphism of the fiber taking any given point to any other will surely not generally guarantee normality of the subgroup (your parenthetical remark); this biholomorphism should be the restriction of a deck transformation.

Comment: Provided the fibers have the homotopy-type of a discrete space, your map has many of the properties of a covering map.  And this is essentially an if and only if statement, via @SamNead's comment.

Comment: What if $F$ is homotopic to a covering space of $X$@RyanBudney?

Comment: I have edited now @AleksandarMilivojević

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you will be interested in the [long exact sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration#Long_exact_sequence_of_homotopy_groups) of homotopy groups associated to a fibration.